# What (input) types of files can avconv convert and to what (output) files?

Tags: multimedia, file-format, convert, avconv

I like to use simple commands (in Thunar custom actions), like `avconv -i %f %f.mp3`.

I can replace `mp3` with `flac` for example - but what other output extensions can be used?

Also, in Thunar custom actions I can select which files to involve the command (audio, video, etc) but which exactly are the input extensions that can be used?

---

I have posted [a similar question on ffmpeg](https://askubuntu.com/q/286624/47206).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an inbuilt list of codecs supported from the version of avconv you have installed.

In a terminal type

```
avconv -formats
```

This will give you a rather long list of supported formats beginning e.g. like below (`D` allows decoding `E` also allows encoding):

```
File formats:
 D. = Demuxing supported
 .E = Muxing supported
 --
  E 3g2             3GP2 format
  E 3gp             3GP format
 D  4xm             4X Technologies format
 D  IFF             IFF format
 D  ISS             Funcom ISS format
 D  MTV             MTV format
 DE RoQ             raw id RoQ format
  E a64             a64 - video for Commodore 64
 D  aac             raw ADTS AAC
 DE ac3             raw AC-3
```

For more information on codecs, and details on their usage see:

- Multimedia Wiki: [Video Codecs](http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=Category%3aVideo_Codecs)
- Multimedia Wiki: [Audio Codecs](http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=Category%3aAudio_Codecs)